# jQuery checkbox tooltip

Tags: jquery, checkbox, tooltip

I use the following jQuery function for tooltip on input text, textarea and dropdown:

```
$(function() {
$("#addmovie-form :input:not(:button):not(:submit):not(:reset)").tooltip({
        position: "center right",
        offset: [-2, 10],
        effect: "fade",
        opacity: 0.7

    });
});
```

I add then a tooltip to a text, textare or dropdown with code:

```
$('#add-titel').prop("title", "my title ...");
```

This is working fine on text, textarea and dropdown inputs.

Now I have also multiple checkboxes inside the form and If I assign a tooltip to the checkbox id's, the tooltip is not displayed.
Also the checkboxes are jumping around on mouseover like this:

[example before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6thRK.jpg)

[example after mousehover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMVTD.jpg)

Does someone have a solution for this?

I also thought, it would be better to put a html table around the whole checkboxes and display the tooltip on table hover. I found some TD or TR jquerys for this, but i can't get it to work on the complete table.

Comment: try to add tool-tip on `checkboxes label` or try to wrap `checkbox in span` and add tooltip on it

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i didn't even know you can do it with span.Thank you, now it is working. I got the code from here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add tool-tip on `checkboxes label` or try to wrap `checkbox in span` and add tooltip on it